# linux + snmp + how to verify snmp.conf

Tags: linux, redhat, snmp

in my redhat linux machine I have the follwing snmp configuration

```
more /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
#dlmod cmaX /usr/lib64/libcmaX64.so
rocommunity ttt 127.0.0.1

syscontact plilunixadm@pl.co.il

rocommunity ttt darapp01.pl.corp
rocommunity ttt  darapp02.pl.corp


syslocation UNKNOWN
trapcommunity ttt
trapsink  plice01.il.pl.corp ttt
```

.

so my target is to verify that snmp.conf configured right and snmp basic sanity as well

I just googled to see what command can check the current  snmp configuration
and I find this:

```
  snmpwalk -v 2c -c   ttt -O e 127.0.0.1|more
  SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux machine01  
  DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (560475) 1:33:24.75
  SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: unixadm@pl.co.il
  SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: machine01 
  SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: UNKNOWN
```

.
.
.

there are a lot of details from the command output

but not understand what actually need to capture from the output in order to be sure that my snmp.conf is OK

second question - what is the string rshedona from the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your snmpd.conf works because snmpwalk return a result.

The string rshedona is the name of the community you have chose.

```
rocommunity rshedona 127.0.0.1
...
rocommunity rshedona darapp01.pl.corp
rocommunity rshedona  darapp02.pl.corp
```

and is the string you have writen in the command snmpwalk :

```
  snmpwalk -v 2c -c   rshedona -O e 127.0.0.1|more
```

`-v` is the version of snmp `-c` the community `-O` the output options
By default, snmpwalk return the result of  the system MIB.